# How to SUM two fields within an SQL query and make a condition for that SUM

Tags: php, sql

I have a table `students` 
and table `room`

The `room` table contains a `capacityField`(int) and `margeField`(int)  of how many student can support.

example :

```
capacityField : 100
margeField : 12
```

I want to retrieve the `rooms` which `capacityField + margeField` is supperior or equal to the total of students.

I made this query:

```
public function fetchSalle(){
    $cmod = $_GET['cmod'];
    $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM etudiants AS etd INNER JOIN filieres AS flr WHERE etd.id_filiere=flr.id_filiere AND etd.id_filiere=$cmod");
    $sth->execute();
    $total = $sth->rowCount();      

    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT *, (capaciteField + margeField) AS Sum FROM salles WHERE Sum>=$total");      
    $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt->fetchAll();       
}
```

but I doesn't work

Comment: need to inner join **on** a condition

Comment: The first query gives me the total of students and then, from that total I can make a query to retrieve rooms(salles) that are supperior or equal to the total of students.

How to do the inner join and where?

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a precise error description, why don't you post the exact error. It's probably related to the `WHERE Sum>=$total`, you need to replace `Sum` with `(capaciteField + margeField)`. Additionally `Sum`is a key word in most DBMSes.

Comment: I think you have typo error on the sql query. `(capaciteField + margeField)`. It should have been `(capacityField + margeField)` if the fieldname is as per you say above. Thanks.

Comment: The first query multiplies the size of `etudiants` by the size of `filieres`.

Comment: @amdixon . . . Unfortunately, MySQL allows this syntax.  It shouldn't, and in every other database as well as the standard, the `on` clause is required.

Comment: @GordonLinoff so what is the documented behaviour when you dont specify a join condition in mysql

Comment: It looks like he has his join condition in the `WHERE` clause. While this is not strictly legal SQL, it works the same as putting it in `ON`.

Comment: When I said "doesn't work"  I meant It gives me no result and i've tried (capaciteField + margeField)>=$total but no result

Comment: Make sure you have PDO exception signalling enabled. You should be getting a SQL error from the second query.

Comment: @amdixon . . . it is a `cross join`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put a `SELECT` alias of the same query in its `WHERE` clause. You either have to use `HAVING`:

```
SELECT *, (capaciteField + margeField) AS Sum 
FROM salles 
HAVING Sum>=$total
```

or you have to repeat the calculation:

```
SELECT *, (capaciteField + margeField) AS Sum 
FROM salles 
WHERE (capaciteField + margeField) >= $total
```

BTW, you can combine both queries into one:

```
SELECT s.*, (capaciteField + margeField) AS Sum
FROM salles AS s
JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
      FROM etudiants AS e
      JOIN filieres AS f ON e.id_filiere = f.id_filiere
      WHERE e.id_filiere = $cmod) AS t
WHERE (capaciteField + margeField) > total
```

Also, you should learn to use prepared queries and `bindParam` instead of substituting variables into the SQL string.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Barmar .. Both of the queries you gave me works fine.. Thanks once again for your help.